# Adding incrementing numbers to nested components in react

Tags: reactjs

This is a simplified version of a problem that I'm trying to solve.

I'm rending a list of `Wrapper` components

```
function App() {
  return (
    {...map(_ => {
      <Wrapper/>;
    })}
  );
}
```

The component `Wrapper` further renders a list (of variable length) of some inputs

```
const Wrapper =  () => {

  return (
    <div className="">
      {...map(_ => {
        return <input/>
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now I need all the inputs to have a data attribute `data-inputnumber` that increments from 0 and up

this could for example result in the following rendered HTML

```
<div>
    <input data-inputnumber="0">
    <input data-inputnumber="1">
</div>
<div>
    <input data-inputnumber="2">
    <input data-inputnumber="3">
    <input data-inputnumber="4">
</div>
<div>
    <input data-inputnumber="5">
    <input data-inputnumber="6">
</div>
<div>
    <input data-inputnumber="7">
    <input data-inputnumber="8">
    <input data-inputnumber="9">
    <input data-inputnumber="10">
</div>
```

Can this be achieved somehow?

Comment: take `[count,setCount] = useState(0)` in `App()` function and pass it to `<Wrapper count={count} setCount={setCount}   />` component. Then inside the both `...map` use `setCount(count+1)` to change the count value and return  `<input data-inputnumber={count}>` inside the `Wrapper` component.

Comment: I did that and it triggered infinite rerender because of calling setCount inside Wrapper component

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a variable in your Wrapper-Component and count up with the `++` - Operator.

```
const Wrapper =  () => {

let inputCounter = 0;

return (
 <div className="">
  {...map(_ => {
    return <input data-inputnumber={inputCounter++}/>
  })}
</div>
);
};
```

You don't need to use `useState()` here. (`useState()` could actually even trigger an infinite loop)

Comment: But this will result in the inputCounter being reset every time a new Wrapper is rendered